# Copyright Label of LaunchScreen at Xcode6

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xcode6

I created a new project by single view application mode at Xcode 6.

There was a LaunchScreen.xib in the created project.
In this xib, copyright label's font size is changed by device.
Look at below image.

[image: Adaptive Copyright Label]

Copyright label's font size at 4inch iPhone is smaller than font size at 5.5inch iPhone.
I couldn't find any size case properties for this. I tried to make my own label, but it have same font size at all devices.

And builtin copyright label had not the height constraint, but any warning was not shown.
My own label has missing height constraint warning.

Who can explain this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is done not by auto-layout but by specifying `Autoshrink` property:

[image]